# QNetworkRequest for generated images

Tags: qt

I am coding a script that lets the user re-download a image to always have the latest version. This works fine for [some static image I found on google](http://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/1.jpg). But when I try to use it on [a generated image](http://stats.outbreak-community.de/sig/2997_1002.png) or [another](https://userb.tsviewer.com/1_t-i/cdSPKuu%2B6P7o7%2BLBOlsJHJNUjSM%3D.png) it returns me HTML code:

```
Error: 0 (Unknown error)
Content-Type: text/html
Content: <html>
<head><title>302 Found</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>302 Found</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>
```

My code so far:

```
def onNetworkReply(self, reply):
    try:
        print("Error: %s (%s)"%(reply.error(), reply.errorString()))
        print("Content-Type: %s"%reply.header(QNetworkRequest.ContentTypeHeader))
        print("Content: %s"%reply.readAll())
        #if reply.header(QNetworkRequest.ContentTypeHeader) == "image/jpeg":
        imgraw = reply.readAll()#.data()#.decode('utf-8')
        temp_dir = gettempdir()
        filename = self.generateAvatarFileName(self.schid)
        tmp = path.join(temp_dir, filename)
        fn = QFile(tmp)
        fn.open(QIODevice.WriteOnly)
        fn.write(imgraw)
        fn.close
        #with open(tmp, 'wb') as f: f.write(imgraw)
        ts3lib.logMessage("Uploading %s as new avatar."%tmp, ts3defines.LogLevel.LogLevel_INFO, "PyTSon Script", 0)
        self.uploadAvatar(self.schid, tmp, filename)
    except:
        from traceback import format_exc
        try: ts3lib.logMessage(format_exc(), ts3defines.LogLevel.LogLevel_ERROR, "PyTSon Script", 0)
        except: print(format_exc())
    reply.deleteLater()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HTTP response [302 Found](https://httpstatuses.com/302) is URL redirect status. You could enable auto redirection (*QNetworkRequest::FollowRedirectsAttribute*) in [QNetworkRequest](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworkrequest.html) if you are using Qt 5.6 or newer.

```
QString url("http://your/url/pic.png");
QNetworkRequest req(QUrl(url));
req.setAttribute(QNetworkRequest::FollowRedirectsAttribute, true);
```

> QNetworkRequest::FollowRedirectsAttribute
>
> Requests only, type: QMetaType::Bool (default: false) Indicates
>   whether the Network Access API should automatically follow a HTTP
>   redirect response or not. Currently redirects that are insecure, that
>   is redirecting from "https" to "http" protocol, are not allowed. (This
>   value was introduced in 5.6.)

Comment: Thanks for the tip, i will definitly try that and give you the checkmark if it worked :)

Comment: What is the simplest solution/workaround for pre Qt 5.6? I'm temporarily using a 32-bit Linux platform and since 5.5.1 is the last version that Qt provide in a binary form for that OS/Processor combination this is not a solution available without doing a complete QT SDK build from source. Sadly the distribution I've got (Devuan 1.0 "Jessie") only offers 5.3.2 so that is even older and does not offer a prepackaged solution. 8-(